# MYSQL - Finding the row in Table a That has all column values in Table B

Tags: mysql

I'm new here in the community and I need your help in MySQL.

We have 3 Tables as follows:

- student
- lectures
- student_visits_lectures(N:M Relationship)

  ```
  student=({id},name,{id})
  lectures=({lid},title{lid})
  student_visits_lectures=({student,lectures})
  ```

What is the query for?:

List all students which visit **all lectures**.

For example:

- We have students
- We have 3 lectures(Math,English,Sport)

Now I want all students which visit all lectures.

Sorry for my broken English and formatting. I'll do my best in the future, but this is very important for me.

Thanks in advance!

Greetings

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add the query you have tried before asking, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Let us see what you have attempted first

Answer (score 0):

first add student's id and lectures's into student_visits_lectures table as foreign keys.
then write query as : select student from student_visits_lectures where sbl.student_id = student.id.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current query:

```
SELECT name FROM student INNER JOIN student_visits_lectures ON student.id=student_visits_lectures.id INNER JOIN lectures ON student_visits_lectures.lid= lectures.lid
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it guys. Thank you for all quick replying.

This is the solution:

We have 3 tables:

```
student
id | name
----------
1  | Jack
2  | Rick

lectures
lid | title
----------
1  | Math
2  | English
3  | Sport

student_visiting_lectures
sid |vlid 
---------
1 | 1
1 | 2
1 | 3
2 | 2
3 | 3
```

**Creating the table and inserting values**

```
CREATE TABLE student(
id INT NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
)ENGINE= InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE lectures(
lid INT NOT NULL,
title VARCHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY(lid)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE svl(
sid INT NOT NULL,
vlid INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(sid,vlid),
FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES student(id),
FOREIGN KEY (vlid) REFERENCES lectures(lid)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO student VALUES(
1,'Jack'),
(2,'Rick');

INSERT INTO lectures VALUES(
1,'Math'),
(2,'English'),
(3,'Sport');

INSERT INTO svl VALUES(
1,1),
(1,2),
(1,3),
(2,1);
```

**And this is the query**

```
SELECT name, title FROM student 
INNER JOIN svl ON id = sid
INNER JOIN lectures ON sid = vlid;
```

Comment: Please, when you want to add details to your question (such as what you have tried), *edit* your question, do not add it as an answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want all students that have done all lectures, you can count how many lectures there are:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as n FROM lectures;
```

Then, per student you can count how many lectures they follow:

```
SELECT student_id, COUNT(*) as n
FROM student_visits_lectures
GROUP BY student_id;
```

And you can filter the students that have followed all lectures:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM student_visits_lectures AS ls LEFT JOIN student AS s ON s.id=ls.student_id
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT lecture_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lectures);
```

See the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/efd670/1).

---

This are the tables I have used:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
   id INT NOT NULL,
   name VARCHAR(64),
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE lectures (
   id INT NOT NULL,
   title VARCHAR(100),
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE student_visits_lectures (
   student_id INT NOT NULL,
   lecture_id INT NOT NULL
);
```